# Sonar C plugin has disappeared

Tags: sonarqube

I've used the C plugin for Sonar for while.
But the plugin library list has recently been updated and seems to indicated the C plugin has been merged with the commercial c++ plugin?
Does that mean that the C plugin is no longer free of charge?
Is the C plugin still active, in terms of developing features and support?

Jesper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C plugin is still available for download and usage.
But it will no longer be supported and will no longer evolve.

Comment: Thanks David. And just to be clear, the c/c++ plugin is not available in the sonarsource version?

Answer (score 0):

The default C/C++/Objective-C plugin for SonarQube is commercial right now. You have to pay to use it. The Sonar Community C /C++ plugin is good. It has many functionalities. Its called sonar-cxx. You can find it Here- https://github.com/wenns/sonar-cxx/wiki/Installation

You can download it from here - https://github.com/wenns/sonar-cxx/releases/tag/cxx-0.9.1